# Get regex working in powershell script

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to rename several files using a regex expression.

```
ck1823000-23.dat
ck1293834-67.dat
lo1230324-99.dat
pk1232131-34.dat
...
```

I want to remove **-XX**
So the result would be like this:

```
ck1823000.dat
ck1293834.dat
lo1230324.dat
pk1232131.dat
...
```

I came up with this regex:

```
(?:.*?)([-\\s].*?).dat
```

But I get this error:

> Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName'
>   failed. The regular expression pattern is not valid

When I run this command:

```
Get-ChildItem . -file -Filter "*.dat" | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace "\(?:.*?)([-\\s].*?).dat\", ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with an empty string.

```
-[^.-]*(?=\\.dat)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qM2pT8/1)

```
Get-ChildItem . -file -Filter "*.dat" | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace "-[^.-]*(?=\\.dat)", ""}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. So I guess I can't use groups to match

Comment: I think you can. REgex : `^(.*?)([-\\s].*?)(\\.dat)$` replacemet string: `$1$3` DEmo http://regex101.com/r/qM2pT8/2

Answer (score 1):

Another option you can use `basename` instead of `name` property

```
Get-ChildItem . -file -Filter "*.dat" | 
   Rename-Item -newname { $_.basename -replace "-.*"}
```